# Relation is a function from domain to power set of range

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $E$ and $F$ be sets. Then $\tau$ can be considered a function from $E$ to $P(F)$ by setting, for each $x \in E$,

$\tau(x) = \{y \in F: (x, y) \in \tau\}$ .

This is a claim from a text, but it doesn't make sense to me. How can $\tau$ be a mapping into $P(F)$ when the elements of its range are members of $F$? If the claim is true, shouldn't $\tau(x)$ be a subset of $F$ rather than an element of $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the "less than" relation on the integers. Let $x$ be the number $7$. Then the author is saying that we can write
$$
\tau(7) = \{ y \in \mathbb Z \mid 7 < y \} = \{8, 9, 10, \ldots\}
$$

A typical element in the range of $\tau$ is the set above, which is an element of the power set of $\mathbb Z$.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks. The uniqueness of $\tau(x)$ is clear in your example, but I'll have to think about how it's guaranteed in general.

Answer (score 1):

This is true in general.

The point is not that $\tau$ **is** a function into the powerset of its range — it isn't, it can't be, $\tau \subseteq E\times F$ — but that it *induces* such a function $\tau'$ in a natural, canonical way.

Note that the domain of $\tau'$ might *not* be all of $E$, but the domain of $\tau'$ will be all of $E$: $x\notin dom(\tau) = \{x\in E\mid \exists y\in F)(x,y)\in \tau\}$, *iff* $\tau'(x) = \emptyset$. So $\tau'$ is always a total function on $E$.

You can recover $\tau$ from $\tau'$:
$$
\tau = \{(x,y)\mid y\in \tau'(x)\}.
$$
Moreover, every relation from $E$ to $F$ is obtained from a function $E\to \mathcal{P}(F)$ in this way.

Comment: I think that your display equation should say $y \in \tau'(x)$ rather than $x \in \tau'(x)$. I also agree that using the letter $\tau$ both for the relation and the associated function into the powerset is a bad idea. But such bad ideas are pretty common in mathematics, alas. As for the domain of $\tau$: there we disagree. If $\tau$ is not a total relation (i.e., there's some $e \in E$ that's not related to anything in $F$) then you simply define $\tau'(e) = \emptyset \subset F$, so that $\tau'$ really *is* a function on $E$. (The recovery strategy still works even with this definition.)

Comment: Yes it should have been $x\in \tau'(y)$ thanks. And... yes you have a point about domains. I will emend accordingly....

Comment: @JohnHughes I incorporated your ideas. Thanks again.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstood, I think it's supposed to say as @JohnHughes put it $y \in \tau'(x)$ since $x\in E$ and $y\in F$ by definition of $\tau \subseteq E \times F$, so it can't be $\tau'(y)$ since it's not defined ($\tau': E \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(F)$).

Comment: @rb612 A typo but a bad one, thanks for catching that.